# Efficient leave-one-out calculation

Tags: r, kernel-density

I am running a simulation that repeatedly calculates cross-validation bandwidth.

I have a following function which I think is terribly inefficient.

```
n <- 200L
x <- rnorm(n)
leave_1_out <- function(h){
  loo <- rep(NA, n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    loo[i] <- density(x[-i], bw=h, from = x[i], to=x[i], n=1)$y
  }
}        
system.time(leave_1_out(0.1))
```

Is any there better, faster method?